# Different World States DB as a mechanism for data security

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts

I am using cross-chaincode to take advantage of the fact that I can store data in isolation in different world states. However, I am not clear whether storing in different world states offers advantages with respect to data security over other mechanisms such as private data collections or creation of multiple channels.

Is there any benchmark that compares these three features?

1. Storage in different world states DB
2. Private Data Collections
3. Different Channels creation

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have only been able to find justification for two of the points: channels and private data collection, which are compared in this link ([Channel and Private Data Collection comparison](http://www.bchainledger.com/2019/12/privacy-features-in-hyperledger-fabric.html)), which contains a [Table to compare channels with PDC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmsOW.png). For now, I will keep the issue open.